# image shows up in every browser except Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, image, google-chrome, safari

I've tried clearing history and caches, but one little img won't open in Chrome or Safari. I've tried other people's computers too. I've checked the code twice. Doesn't make sense!

[Here's a Link](http://www.adammureiko.com/1819.html). It's the image at the bottom.

```
<div id="showcase_box">
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Full-Page Magazine Ad" href="images/1819/ad.jpg">
<img src="images/1819/ad2.jpg" alt="Sea Salt Ad" />
</a>
</div>
```

Here's a [link](http://adammureiko.com/images/1819/ad2.jpg) to the image itself, just to show it's up there.

Any ideas? Tell me if I should supply more data about the problem. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, here's the related CSS:

Here is the [design-related CSS](http://www.adammureiko.com/style.css).

I'm using FancyBox for a jQuery shadowbox, so here's the CSS for that plugin, related to the image thumbnail:

[Link](http://adammureiko.com/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.css)

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Works in chrome for me.

Comment: not for me. The `img` tag isn't even there in the inspector.

Comment: You're using the "id" attribute incorrectly. You're giving the same "id" value to all of your "showcaseBox" containers, and that's not allowed.  Use a "class" property to categorize elements.  An "id" value has to be unique on the page.

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and JS  that affect the image element. How it being generated etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the generated HTML

`<img src="images/1819/ad2.jpg" alt="Sea Salt Ad" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0">`

If it's not on your HTML, it should be coming from somewhere in your javascript code, I just gave a fast look and couldn't find...

Comment: <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Full-Page Magazine Ad" href="images/1819/ad.jpg"><img src="images/1819/ad2.jpg" alt="Sea Salt Ad"></a> Is the code that is shown for me in chrome

Comment: In chrome, I don't even see an `img`, just a `href`. In Firefox it looks fine.

Comment: I changed those attributes in the '<img style="">' section and it's working perfectly now! Thanks!!

Comment: I also changed the image file name and made a new directory to experiment with...

Comment: @adamdesign I am seeing this same behavior in safari >= 7.0. on my own project. What attributes did you change?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You have `display: none !important` applied to the element

***EDITED***

This is a known image issue with chrome. It has to do with the height calculation. If you add the following CSS to your stylesheet it should fix it

`ul.thumbs img {height:50px;}`

Comment: The issue is the Javascript is failing for some users, and not for others.  All of the static styles are removed from the code I see.  See my post above.